# About tf.gfile.FastGFile and cv2 mat

Tags: tensorflow

This is the code for reading an image from disk:

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(imagePath, 'rb').read()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

But now I want to capture frames from videos using Python and opencv, and then classify captured mat images using this model.
I tried :

```
 image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
 print(image_data)
 imgRGB = cv2.imread(image_path)
 r, buf = cv2.imencode(".jpg", imgRGB)
 bytes_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(buf)).tobytes()
 print(bytes_image)
```

and I got two similar result，but it is not the same.
`b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x00"Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00........
    b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x02.......`

And when I called "sess.run",I found that the final result is not the same.How can I solve this?